# Camunda Modular Version 7 - User Task - Forms

Tags: forms, camunda, camunda-modeler

I am new to Camunda and I am trying to create a user task with form. I am facing a issue where I am able to deploy the process using rest and i can see the process running in the localhost using the cockpit app. the issue is the form i associated with the user task does not show up in the tasklist for that particular user task, it just appear a blank space. I am not sure what I am missing.

[image: Here’s the bpmn process]
[image: Here’s the form’s config (the form reference is the same as the form key):]

And here's the form's code:
**form_2.form**

```
{
“components”: [
{
“text”: “# Pedido de encomenda”,
“label”: “Text view”,
“type”: “text”,
“layout”: {
“row”: “Row_1bjcb7b”,
“columns”: null
},
“id”: “Field_1my6nm6”
},
{
“label”: “Nome”,
“type”: “textfield”,
“layout”: {
“row”: “Row_0ew90jr”,
“columns”: null
},
“id”: “Field_0fzsn93”,
“key”: “textfield_qaqcrl”
},
{
“label”: “Quantidade”,
“type”: “number”,
“layout”: {
“row”: “Row_02ie1wd”,
“columns”: null
},
“id”: “Field_1rvdt1i”,
“key”: “number_uxf2lv”
}
],
“type”: “default”,
“id”: “form_2”,
“exporter”: {
“name”: “Camunda Modeler”,
“version”: “5.19.0”
},
“executionPlatform”: “Camunda Platform”,
“executionPlatformVersion”: “7.20.0”,
“schemaVersion”: 14
}
```

**form_4.form**

```
{
“components”: [
{
“text”: “# Confirmar encomenda”,
“label”: “Text view”,
“type”: “text”,
“layout”: {
“row”: “Row_0sa7sa7”,
“columns”: null
},
“id”: “Field_1lem99g”
},
{
“values”: [
{
“label”: “Sim”,
“value”: “Sim”
},
{
“label”: “Não”,
“value”: “Nao”
}
],
“label”: “Deseja prosseguir?”,
“type”: “radio”,
“layout”: {
“row”: “Row_0ty0ih0”,
“columns”: null
},
“id”: “Field_0b8vqpc”,
“key”: “radio_nndb4r”
}
],
“type”: “default”,
“id”: “form_4”,
“exporter”: {
“name”: “Camunda Modeler”,
“version”: “5.19.0”
},
“executionPlatform”: “Camunda Platform”,
“executionPlatformVersion”: “7.20.0”,
“schemaVersion”: 14
}
```

Camunda Platform 7.20.0
Modeler version 5.19.0
Windows 11